# What did I do wrong with the command SBB in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

There is something wrong with my code because the correct answer for

> 12,341,234 - 22,222,222

is

> -9880988

while the answer I keep getting from my program is

> 64,750,557

What did I do wrong?

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.DATA
.CODE
start:
  mov ax, 1234d
  mov bx, 1234d
  mov cx, 2222d
  mov dx, 2222d
  sub ax, cx
  sbb bx, dx
  neg ax
  neg bx
  mov ax, 4c00h
  int 21h
END start
```

Comment: You are not calculating what you think you are. Your input in `bx:ax` is `(1234<<16)+1234=80872658` and `cx:dx=(2222<<16)+2222=145623214` and `145623214-80872658=64750556`.

Comment: Your error is that you are trying to subtract decimal numbers indicated the the `d` suffix, but your code is for subtracting hexadecimal numbers. `2222d<<16 + 2222d`is not `2222h<<16 + 2222h`.

Comment: Also you got the negation wrong.

Comment: @zx485 that code is for subtracting binary numbers and that's how those values will get encoded during assembly. He just misunderstood how split 12341234 into 16:16 bits, the correct split is 188:20466. Once he would write `mov ax,20466` `mov bx,188`, he would have binary representation of 12341234 in bx:ax, etc... the `sub+sbb` pair doesn't bother about source formatting.

Comment: @Ped7g: Of course you're right. But the result depends on the number format of the input values. My comment was referring to the difference between the two number formats.

Comment: @zx485 The result as presented by OP also strongly depends on how/where it is read and in which formatting... of course *I* understand what you mean, but connecting the decimal and hexadecimal to the subtraction itself is probably the most unfortunate way how to describe it, as that subtraction is either way binary only and problem is everywhere else... I think I will try to produce rather full answer for this one, it's surprisingly so much of it, that it can't fit to comment reasonably, as we two are just now demonstrating. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12,341,234 - 22,222,222 *is* -9,880,988 - so far, so good.

So let's see the code:

```
  mov ax, 1234d
  mov bx, 1234d
```

And here is the first problem, judging by the rest of the code, the intent of these two instructions is to load value 12341234 into 32 bit register pair `bx:ax`, but the code written above will load into `bx:ax` value 80,872,658. (actually you can interpret that `bx:ax` as 12,341,234 by your own custom rules defining that `value = bx*10000+ax`, but your following code doing subtraction does not respect such rule. So this note is just demonstration, that the way how I got "80,872,658" is most natural ("native") to the CPU, but not the only possible one - for the rest of answer let's assume that all values are binary encoded in "CPU native" way and then 1234d:1234d *is* interpreted as 80,872,658, for any other custom rules you would have to write **lot** more code, which would respect those rules and calculate basic arithmetic according to those).

From CPU point of view: it does execute machine code, which is binary encoded stream of byte value (it has no idea how your text did look). To get this machine code from your source, the assembler will transform the source-code text "mov ax, 1234d" into bits "1011_1000 1101_0010 0000_0100" (three bytes, when formatted hexadecimal "B8 D2 04" or when formatted decimal "184 210 4", but computer memory does use bits, so the binary representation is sort of what CPU really does operate upon).

That first byte 184 will CPU decode as "this is instruction `mov ax,<16 bit immediate>` and following two bytes will encode the immediate itself" and so the values 210 and 4 represent the value 1234.

The x86 CPU is little-endian type of machine, so two bytes "1101_0010 0000_0100", after being read from memory in this order, are concatenated into 16 bit value 0000_0100_1101_0010 - the "little-endian" means, that first byte is least significant, and ending byte is most significant, so they are like in reversed order (4, 210).

One byte is 8 bits, thus it can accommodate 256 combinations (2<sup>8</sup> = 256, 2 is amount of possible states per single bit: 0 or 1, 8 is number of bits).

If you write numbers in "human" way, you go like ...,8,9,10 ... notice you suddenly use two digits for value 10. Why? Because you exhausted all available single digits, so you bump by +1 the "upper" digit (which was hidden "0" before), and reset "bottom" digit to 0 and start over = 10,11,...,19,20 ... again after exhausting bottom digit space, you bump the upper part).

Now whole byte can store 256 combinations of distinct 8-bit-patterns, so if you interpret those bit patterns as integers starting at 0, one byte can cover range 0..255 for whole integers. If you are counting in "bytes", you will need only single byte up to value 255, then after that you will hit the first "10" situation (exhausting single byte), and you will have to bump "upper" byte by +1 and reset bottom byte to 0.

In math terms, the human decimal way of writing numbers forms value *v* = sum( digit<sub>k</sub> * 10<sup>k</sup> ) for *k* going from 0 upward up to "number of digits - 1". I.e. 1234 = 1 * 10<sup>3</sup> + 2 * 10<sup>2</sup> + 3 * 10<sup>1</sup> + 4 * 10<sup>0</sup>.

In the similar way for bytes, but having 256 "digits", the value represented by multiple bytes is *v* = sum( byte<sub>k</sub> * 256<sup>k</sup> ).

I.e. those two bytes 210 and 4 represent value 210 * 256<sup>0</sup> + 4 * 256<sup>1</sup> = 210 * 1 + 4 * 256 = 210 + 1024 = **1234**.

Or in it's binary form, the 0000_0100_1101_0010 encodes value 1 * 2<sup>10</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>7</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>6</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>4</sup> + 1 * 2<sup>1</sup> = 1024 + 128 + 64 + 16 + 2 = 1234

It's the same value all the time, just encoded in different ways, once as two 256-digits "4,210", or as four decimal digits 1,2,3,4, or as eleven binary digits 1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0 ... i.e. the same value encoded as base-256, base-10 and base-2 number.

The CPU naturally operates in base-2, but assembly programmers love to use base-16 (hexadecimal) formatting of values, because in hexadecimal every single digit represents exactly four bits (0 = 0000, 1 = 0001, 2 = 0010, ..., D = 1101, E = 1110, F = 1111). With a bit of practice, you convert in your head between hexa and binary format of particular value.

And here's how you probably ended writing those two lines of code. Maybe you have seen somewhere something like "I have 32 bit value 12345678, so I will load it into two registers as `mov bx,1234` `mov ax,5678`" - which works well, as long as all those numbers are hexadecimal! Because then "5678" is actually 16 bit value (four hexa digits = 4 * 4 = 16 bits), which is precisely the whole size of `ax`, so once you fill the `ax` with `5678h`, the remaining part `1234h` goes just like that into the "upper" 16 bit register `bx`.

But using the same visual split of decimal value 12341234 will not work. Value 12341234 when formatted in base 16 is `0BC4FF2h`, so by using code:

```
mov  ax,4FF2h  ; or ; mov ax,20466  ; or ; mov ax,(12341234 MOD 65536)
mov  bx,00BCh  ; or ; mov bx,188    ; or ; mov bx,(12341234 DIV 65536)
; if your assembler supports MOD/DIV syntax like that...
; then all above are identical instructions resulting into
; the same binary machine code
```

you are loading register pair `bx:ax` with binary representation of value 12341234.

I.e. 188 * 65536 + 20466 = 12341234. (65536 = 2<sup>16</sup>, because now this value is encoded in base-65536, as "single digit" is whole `word` in this case, `word` is 16 bits => 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536 total possible combinations.

---

So once you will understand how integer values are encoded in computers, and why 12341234 is represented by two word values 188,20466, and you will fix your init of `bx:ax` and `dx:cx` according to it (22222222 = 153158Eh = words 153h, 158Eh = 339, 5518 => i.e. `mov cx,5518` `mov dx,339`) - the subtraction will do this:

```
  sub ax, cx  ; 20466 - 5518 = 14948 (no borrow)
  sbb bx, dx  ; 188 - 339 - 0(no_borrow) = -151 (borrow=yes)
```

Now this -151, 14948 word pair encodes value -151 * 65536 + 14948 = -9880988. Isn't it familiar?

Unfortunately the next part:

```
  neg ax
  neg bx
```

Doesn't make much sense... while word pair 151,-14948 *does* represent value 9880988, in native 32-bit value encoding only the top value has "sign", so 151,-14948 is actually interpreted as 151,50588 and that encodes value 9946524 (nothing to do with -9880988).

To encode value 9880988 you would need word pair: 150, 50588 and the correct way (one of possible [correct ways](http://x86asm.net/articles/working-with-big-numbers-using-x86-instructions/#Negation)) to negate binary value by separate components is:

```
  not  ax
  not  bx  ; first "one's complement" is done
  ; "neg" is two's complement, so let's fix it one's to two's
  add  ax,1
  adc  bx,0
```

Again deeper understanding of how values are encoded in computer is required, why this works, but let's get quickly at least through example with those values... not(-151, 14948) is (150, 50587), then 50587+1 is 50588, no carry happened, thus 150+0 = 150 -> word pair "150, 50588", that is value 9880988 encoded as two 16 bit words.